# Searching for all strings using an array in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Im trying to get all values (in this case strings) from a column A which have a "house" in it via an array and put the results in column B started with cell B1. With vlookup I only get one result:

```
=SVERWEIS("*"&"house"&"*";A:A;1;FALSCH)
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit in more relevant information to reproduce what you are trying. Include your own attempt (no matter how poor).

Comment: Sry – i edited it. Now better? :)

Comment: sample data would be very helpfull. Even a screenshot if possible.

Comment: ok, cool. now better? do you have a solution for me ;)

Comment: Yes, see the answer below. However, that screenshot is Google Spreadsheets. You sure you want Excel tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use (having Excel O365)

```
=FILTER(A2:A9,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*house*",A2:A9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah cool, thank you! I convert the formula into spreadsheet and it worked. Thank you!